# How do I render data from a callback function in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I making requests to my Django backend, the data is a list of information. What I need to do is is render a piece of HTML for each item in the list, this list is retrieved asynchronously. However in the `render()` where I'm returning some HTML I can't place that in a asynchronous function. I've never had to use this with react:

```
var allLeads = []
// get a list of all the leads from the Django backend 
 const getAllLeads =  (callback) => {
  const leads = fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/leads/", {method:'get', headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}})
  .then(function(result){
    //console.log("result", await result.text())
    return result.text()
  })
  .then(async function(result){
    // console.log("R2", result)
    allLeads = result.slice()
    // console.log("ALL", allLeads)
    callback(allLeads)
    return await leads
  })
```

My component class:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dataType: "", // store the type of data for the type of operation that should be sent to the backend. For example "create" will have the data for creating data
    data: {},
    displayOptions: false
    } 


  leads = []
  async handleChange(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    this.state.displayOptions = true
  }

  render() {

      getAllLeads(function(data){
        console.log("DATA", data)
        return data
      })


    return (
        <div className="App">
          test

        </div>
      )

  }
}

export default Home;
```

In `getAllLeads` I'm successfully logging the data, but I have no idea how I would go about using that data inside my return function. Or how would I even use asynchronous data to set the state to a list for example so I could display the information inside the state?

Comment: I think you don't need to use async, then and also callback all once. All of them are trying to solve the same problem, call back hell.

Comment: I know I've tried many ways, but fetch() is asynchronous natively anyway. So I'd have the problem no matter what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of problems there, first, to assign a value to the state you have to use `this.setState({})`. Since under the hood it will trigger a re-computation of the React Fiber. Another suggestion I would give would be to trigger the API call on `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook, you can make him async and then just await the result and call `this.setState({ data })`.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    dataType: "",
    data: {},
    leads: [],
    displayOptions: false
  }

 async componentDidMount() {
   const leads = await getAllLeads((data) => return data);
   this.setState({ leads });
 }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          test

        </div>
      )

  }
}

export default Home;
```

I would also advise to refactor your function to get the leads since returning from inside a then returns nothing. Use `async` and `await` instead.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I was trying to think of a way to fetch during the load or something like that. I had no idea however, this seems to work for me

Comment: I have a quick question. When I log the value of `this.state.leads` the value logs 4 times, the first 2 times it's undefined, the next two its the value I want. This also seems to be cause an error, because I can't use the value of `state` in my return function, because the return function seems to use the first instance of `this.state.leads` which is undefined. Why is this?

Comment: Because setting state happens when you don't have data yet, so you need to only call the setState when the async call succeeds.
What you can do is you would render a loading spinner if `!this.state.leads.length`.
Also use `React.PureComponent` to memoise the props it gets and prevent re-render if they don't change.

Comment: Give a default state value to leads that isn't nullish/undefined.

Comment: Thanks again, how exactly do I only call the setState if it succeeds? I just want to make sure the state is full before render is called

Comment: Sorry I didn't even notice your comment about changing the value of leads. That seems to be fixing that issue, thanks man!